# Determine storage requirements for a MySQL row

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I obtained this error with a new table on my web-app:

```
Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

So I reduced the lenght of some `varchar` column in order to stay below that value.

I would like to know how many bytes could be used by a full populated row.

Is there a command to know: how many byte are still free before reach 65535 in a row?

Comment: what is your field datatype and size ?

Comment: @unknown I think he would to get the current row size given any combination of datatype and length, in ordert to know how is far from 65535 limit.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: From http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DatabaseBestPractices : "As a general rule of thumb, if a table contains more than 20 fields it may be improperly normalized."

Comment: According to my research, there is no simple command to get the requested value. You need to calculate this value yourself by querying columns' types and table charset (say utf8 wants 3 bytes per char into your row size limit, while utf16 will only take 2), if there's a null (+1), maybe more, can't yet find extra data.

Comment: @Ruud Yes I know, I have this situation because I used Single Table Strategyin JPA Environment, I tryed with a full normalized table (Joined Table Strategy) but I reach the maximum number of join..http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_inher.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method below is **incomplete** since the `CASE` only covers those types I needed (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html) for the others). The other types get a "8" which is usually okay, unless you have `CHAR` or `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns. `TEXT` and `BLOB` count for 256 bytes each.

Everybody is welcome to contribute :-)

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE,
CASE SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLUMN_TYPE,'(',1)
WHEN 'decimal' THEN FLOOR((NUMERIC_PRECISION+8)/9)*4
WHEN 'integer' THEN 4
WHEN 'varchar' THEN CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH
WHEN 'bits' THEN FLOOR((NUMERIC_PRECISION+7)/8)
WHEN 'float' THEN 8
ELSE 4
END AS size
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='<the name of your database>'
AND TABLE_NAME='<the name of your table>';
```

and so:

```
SELECT SUM(size) FROM (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE,
    CASE
    ...
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='<the name of your database>'
    AND TABLE_NAME='<the name of your table>'
) AS result;
```